# How can I edit the Resources.resources file on .net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, visual-studio-code, resources

On by application when I double click on the `Resources.resources` file, it says the document is unsupported, yet when I use a 3rd party application such as dnspy and I put my application inside of that I'm able to see the code. How can I edit the code contents inside the `Resources.resources` file in VS Code?

Note: the the build action for `resources.resources` is set to  "Embedded Resource".

[What I see when I use "Dnspy" to look at the code, I can see the "code" under Resources.resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUS1t.png)

[What I see when I use "vscode" There is no dropdown for "resources.resources" so I can't modify the "code" which is shown when I use Dnspy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwZHV.png)

I haven't been able to try anything as I keep getting the same message when trying to open the `Resources.resources` file. I have tried to re-name it to `Resources.txt` that allowed me to open it in a text document and view the "code" but when I changed the file name back to `Resources.recources` it messed up my whole application.

Comment: Why would you need to open that binary file? Its content reflects what resources you have added in your Project (`Project->Properties->Resources`). Use the dedicated tools to change whatever resources you have added. If that's a WinForms Project, probably better use Visual Studio

Comment: The content of .resources files is normally compiled from .resx files. You can look at and edit those instead (they're basically xml files).